# JSON file content not loading in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I've seen a couple similar responses but they don't address my problem. Complete novice in html/JS.

JSON file, hosted on remote webserver:

```
[
  {"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe"},
  {"firstName": "Anna", "lastName": "Smith"},
  {"firstName": "Peter", "lastName": "Jones"}
]
```

Here is my JS code. The `$http.get` is to a website that lets you store JSON data into a temporary webserver.

automate.js:

```
var parsefile = angular.module("parser", []);

parsefile.controller("parserCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/wpkh").then(function(response) {
    $scope.stuff = response.data;
  });
});
```

And a part of my HTML code is:

```
<div ng-app="parser" ng-controller="parserCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in stuff">
      {{ stuff.firstName }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="automate.js"></script>
```

But when I run it, the only thing that prints is literally `{{stuff.firstName}}`.

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
<li ng-repeat="x in stuff">
    {{ stuff.firstName }}
 </li>
```

which will try to print the `stuff's` `firstName`. Change it into

```
<li ng-repeat="x in stuff">
    {{ x.firstName }}
 </li>
```

And also try to check if your server returns any data, which you assign to the `$scope.stuff`

Comment: Dumbest mistake I've ever spent 3 hours on. I guess it happens to all programmers...thanks for the fresh eyes!